# rake db:fixtures:load on factory_girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, fixtures

I used "rake db:fixtures:load" to insert dummy datas into development db.  I start using factory_girl.  Are there any way to insert datas in RAILS_ROOT/spec/factories/*.rb to development db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factories are not intended to fill the database. They will generate random data for your object attributes (unless otherwise specified). Hence, it won't fill the development database with defined data.

What you should use here are seeds. More info on:

http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/5/13/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-database-seeding
and
http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/20-isolating-seed-data

Comment: Thank you, jbescoyez.I usually use seeds for insert master data like country name, states or category for all environments.